# Airflow: Concurrency with respect to dag path

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Suppose I have a dag with deep concurrency-compatible paths:

```
   B3 <-- B2 <-- B1 <-- B0 
  / 
C 
  \
   A3 <-- A2 <-- A1 <-- A0
```

Where each path above can be solved concurrently. However, if one of the branches above is failing (for example, if `B0, A0` are sensors and `B0` evaluates to `true` while `A0` is still waiting, then the rest of the `B` branch should still execute.

However, although I am able to get task concurrency, the entire dag is stuck at the `B0, A0` task, rather than advancing along the `B0` path while `A0` waits.

How do I configure Airflow to advance along each path, rather than getting blocked at a task if one branch is blocked?

---

Or is the only solution to create many mini-dags?  It seems as if the executor is favoring parallelization across only one level of nodes over vertical execution -- i.e., it is performing breadth only calculations.

Comment: By any chance, do all your tasks A0, A1.., B0, B1.. belonging to some [Airflow pool](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=pool) having just 1 slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bit of a trick at first due to the naming convention:

```
// I am using the following convention: filename(variable name or description)

// conceptually, 
C = airflow.cfg(dag_concurrency) * dag.py(dag concurrency for tasks)
C <= airflow.cfg(parallelism)
```